How to do a VR walkthrough In Unreal?
On Unity, I did a VR project. A walkthrough. On that project, I just switched the materials of the skybox using the below script
public void SwitchtoNextSkybox(int indx){
       RenderSettings.skybox=skyboxMats[indx];
       
    }

each material has a shader  "Skybox/Cubemap". My question is how can I do this in an unreal?
(I just started Unreal a few days ago).I created a VR project. i checked it with VR preview. its working.
